# using two css styles for table td

Tags: css, html-table

Here's what I want to do (simplified example):

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td style = "border:2px solid green">stuff1 </td>
  <td style = "border:2px solid green">stuff2 </td>
  <td style = "border:2px solid green">stuff3 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style = "border:1px solid red">stuff4 </td>
  <td style = "border:1px solid red">stuff5 </td>
  <td style = "border:1px solid red">stuff6</td>
```

This gives precisely the right result, one row bordered in green, the next in red, but I'd like to get rid of all those "style" statements.

I tried several ways to cascade css for this, but couldn't figure out one that would work.  The closest I got was:

```
<head>
<style>
  .test {
    font-size: 15px;
  }

  .test td {
    border: 2px solid green
  }

  .test td a{
     border: 1px solid red
  }

 </style>
 </head>

<body>
<table  class = "test">
   <tr>
      <td>stuff1 </td>
      <td>stuff2 </td>
      <td>stuff3 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td><a>stuff4</a> </td>
      <td><a>stuff5</a> </td>
      <td><a>stuff6</a> </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
```

This almost worked.  The top row was bordered in green.  But the bottom row was bordered in both red and green.

Could someone explain to me how to set up my css so that I can get the result I want.

**************Well, I found a solution using .test th { for the second color.  But this does not solve anything if I want a third color.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a class to the second set of tds. See below for the code or check the Codepen for a working example.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .test {
          font-size: 15px;
        }
        td {
          border: 2px solid green;
        }
        td.red {
          border: 1px solid red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="test">
        <tr>
            <td>stuff1</td>
            <td>stuff2</td>
            <td>stuff3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="red">stuff4</td>
            <td class="red">stuff5</td>
            <td class="red">stuff6</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NzygNV

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this as well, Like keeping css classes in a separate css file and then just adding a link tag pointing towards the css file in the html where you have your table.Refer link below for same.

```css
       .tbl {
       font-size: 15px;
     }
     td {
       border: 2px solid green;
     }
     td.red {
       border:1px solid red;
     }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<!-- you can ad link to css here -->
</head>
<body>
 <table class="tbl">
  <tr>
   <td>column1</td>
   <td>column2</td>
   <td>column3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
   <td class="red">data1</td>
   <td class="red">data2</td>
   <td class="red">data3</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PaQJNK